# Language switching shortcut not working

Tags: shortcut-keys, language-support, input-language

I have the standard <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut for changing languages in Ubuntu 18.04, but pressing the combination does nothing.
What could be wrong?

Comment: Does super + space work for you?

Comment: Sorry, it was super + space - and it doesn't work :(

Comment: If you want to get it back as super + space, open **tweak tools**, go to `Keyboard & Mouse` > **Additional Layout Options** > **Switching to another layout**, then check win + space